# What does "apples to apples" phrase mean?

Tags: idioms

I came along this phrase in a sentence like so

> ... can be compared **apples to apples**

I guess it has something to do with *apples to apples* game, but I couldn't figure it out. What does this idiomatic phrase mean.

Comment: The Apples to Apples party game is not a popular enough game to have spawned the phrase.

Comment: In fact, it's quite the opposite - the game *Apples to Apples* takes its name **from** the idiom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comparing  *apples to apples* means comparing things that can reasonably be compared, while the phrase *[apples to oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_to_oranges)* often is used to represent a comparison that is unreasonable or perhaps impossible.

As noted in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_to_oranges),

> The idiom, *comparing apples and oranges*, refers to the apparent differences between items which are popularly thought to be incomparable or incommensurable, such as apples and oranges. The idiom may also be used to indicate that a false analogy has been made between two items, such as where an apple is faulted for not being a good orange.

Comment: As a concrete example, if you compare two people's wealth by comparing their latest paychecks, you are probably comparing "apples to oranges", since one person may be paid once a month while another may be paid every week. An "apples to apples" comparison would be to compare their yearly income.

Comment: "comparing apples to [_or_ and] oranges" is much more commonly used. A derivation of that phrase, to "compare apples to apples", is not commonly used, but would be quickly understand to mean that you're comparing or judging _like_ things.